# Setting classpath for Oracle JDBC jar in centos

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, jdbc, jar

I am fairly new to Linux, I am trying to set my jar files for OJDBC in my classpath but so far have not found any good examples for a beginner such as me.

I will list the my paths for Jar file below. Can someone provide me with example or how to step by step set my class path with the commands. I would really appreciate it. I would like to set this path in my project which I am using it in.

Jar file:
/home/ssingh/Downloads/oracle.jar

Project:
/opt/savi/Workspace/SgRecc/bin/PerVal.class

Answer (score 0):

Setting up the Class Path
To use the driver, the JAR archive named postgresql.jar if you built from source, otherwise it will likely be (named with the following convention: postgresql-*[server version]*.*[build number]*.jdbc*[JDBC version]*.jar, for example postgresql-8.0-310.jdbc3.jar) needs to be included in the class path, either by putting it in the CLASSPATH environment variable, or by using flags on the java command line.

For instance, assume we have an application that uses the JDBC driver to access a database, and that application is installed as /usr/local/lib/myapp.jar. The PostgreSQL™ JDBC driver installed as /usr/local/pgsql/share/java/postgresql.jar. To run the application, we would use:

```
export CLASSPATH=/usr/local/lib/myapp.jar:/usr/local/pgsql/share/java/postgresql.jar:.
java MyApp
```

Comment: [root@savi local]# export CLASSPATH= /home/ssingh/Jar\ Libs/ojdbc6.jar:/opt/savi/Workspace/SgRecc/src/DBConn.java DBConn
bash: export: `/home/ssingh/Jar Libs/ojdbc6.jar:/opt/savi/Workspace/SgRecc/src/DBConn.java': not a valid identifier @ArjunChaudhary

Comment: It gives me the following error when trying your command to export the path.

Comment: i look up the link for u